# Como Detectar Recursos DOM e API

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como saber se o navegador suporta a certos *métodos*, *propriedades* e *eventos*.

Verificando se um objeto `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, `addEventListener`, `classList` existe via Javascript.

Tive tentando algo com `if .. else` uma estrutura de controle de fluxo baseado em uma condição.

## Exemplo

```
// Criando o elemento para verificar 
var elem = document.createElement('classList');

if(elem != "undefined"){

alert ('Existe sim.');

} else {

alert ('Não existe.');

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o operador [**`in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) para checar se uma determinada propriedade existe no objeto, por exemplo:

```js
if('querySelector' in document){
  alert("Suporta 'querySelector()'.");
}

if('classList' in document.createElement('div')){
  alert("Suporta 'classList'.");  
}
```